# Mixing CTRunDraw and drawAtPoint

Tags: python, objective-c, pdf, core-text, pyobjc

I wrote a module that provides several methods to render text and create PDF files. Now I find that using Core Text along with higher level text rendering messes up the size of the Core Text layout. The later is mainly displayed too large.

*Scenario:*

- Create a PDF context
- Beginn a page
- Render text via `CTRunDraw` (B) *
- End a page
- Close PDF context
- Save PDF

*) This gets rendered properly, as expected. *But only as long as I don’t draw* any text using a `NSAttributedString` and `drawAtPoint_` (A) before.

This means, both methods work perfectly on their own, but the core text drawing gets too large when they both come together.

Is there something to take care of when saving and restoring the graphics context? I tried almost anything. I can put some code here, but it’s quite a lot and in a complex setup, so if you can specify what you exactly want to see, please let me know.

**(A)** The high level text drawing:

```
class Text(object):

    def __init__(self, text="", font="Monaco", fontSize=12, position=None ):
        self.text = text
        self.font = font
        self.fontSize = fontSize
        self.position = position
        self.fontRGBColor = 0, 1, 1, 1

    def drawText(self):
        textAttributes = {}
        textAttributes[NSFontAttributeName] = NSFont.fontWithName_size_( self.font, self.fontSize )
        textAttributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = NSColor.colorWithCalibratedRed_green_blue_alpha_( *self.fontRGBColor )
        textAttributedString = NSAttributedString.alloc().initWithString_attributes_( self.text, textAttributes )
        textAttributedString.drawAtPoint_((self.position[0], self.position[1]))
```

**(B)** The core text method:

```
class TextBox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.font = "Monaco"
        self.fontSize = 12
        self.text = "This is my Text"
        self.fontColor = 0, 1, 1, 0, 0.75

        self.pdfContext = NSGraphicsContext.currentContext().graphicsPort()


    def drawTextBox(self):
        CGContextSaveGState(self.pdfContext)

        myBounds = (0, 0), (100, 100)
        posX, posY = myBounds[0]
        width, height = myBounds[1]

        self.fontObject = NSFont.fontWithName_size_(self.font, self.fontSize)
        self.fontAttributes = {}
        self.fontAttributes[NSFontAttributeName] = self.fontObject
        self.fontAttributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = NSColor.colorWithDeviceCyan_magenta_yellow_black_alpha_(*self.fontColor)

        TextBoxWithFeaturesAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString.alloc().initWithString_attributes_(self.text, self.fontAttributes)
        setter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(TextBoxWithFeaturesAttributedString)
        path = CGPathCreateMutable()

        CGPathAddRect(path, None, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height))
        box = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(setter, (0, 0), path, None)
        ctLines = CTFrameGetLines(box)
        origins = CTFrameGetLineOrigins(box, (0, len(ctLines)), None)

        for i, (originX, originY) in enumerate(origins):
            ctLine = ctLines[i]
            bounds = CTLineGetImageBounds(ctLine, self.pdfContext)
            if bounds.size.width == 0:
                continue
            ctRuns = CTLineGetGlyphRuns(ctLine)
            for ctRun in ctRuns:
                CGContextSetTextPosition(self.pdfContext, posX + originX, posY + originY)
                CTRunDraw(ctRun, self.pdfContext, (0, 0))

        CGContextRestoreGState(self.pdfContext)
```

Many thanks and appreciations in advance.